# Response.Redirect, Access source page data from target page

Tags: asp.net

I have two ASP.NET Web Pages (Page1.aspx and Page2.aspx), Page1.aspx contains few TextBox controls and a Button Control.

On Click Event of Button Control i redirect user to Page2.aspx using **Response.Redirect** method.

How do i access source page data (TextBox values in Page1.aspx) from target page (Page2.aspx).

*I don't want to use Cross-Page Postback or Server.Transfer method*

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to persist that data somewhere.  The way `Response.Redirect` works is by telling the client (the web browser) to make a new request for the specified resource.  This essentially means that the old resource is abandoned.  Think of each request made by the client as unique and stand-alone.

An easy way to persist the values is to store them in [Session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) on `Page1` just before calling `Response.Redirect`.  Then, in `Page2` you can retrieve those values from Session state.

Something like:

**Page1**

```
//...
Session["SomeValue"] = TextBox1.Text;
Session["SomeOtherValue"] = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
//...
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
```

**Page2**

```
//...
// Note: The following can have some additional type checking and input/value checking added
var someValue = Session["SomeValue"];
var someOtherValue = Session["SomeOtherValue"];
//...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply David, that means session object is the only way if we use response.redirect, there is no other way?

Comment: @Faizal Balsania: Well, you could persist it in lots of places, technically... Query string values in the redirect, session state, application state, a local database, a database server, a file, etc.  Session state is a very common place to persist it.  Which place is best is a design question for you, really.  Query string variables would be very RESTful and clean, but makes the URL long and ugly and may show the user more than you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Try using session variables

in page 1

```
Session["field1"] = textbox1.Text;
```

in page 2

```
string page1text = Session["field1"];
```